# Sent e-mail from Laravel goes to spam. Mailgun

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I have created mailgun account and updated all mx, spf, dkim records on my VPS server.

I have updated my `.env` and `config/mail.php` files with my mailgun credentials.

However, when I send an email to gmail from my laravel application, it goes to the spam folder every time.

I have tried to send a plain text message without any links inside, but the result is still the same.

Here is the code that I am using to send the email:

```
Mail::raw('Account confirmation email', function($message) use($data)
{
   $message->subject('Mailgun and Laravel are awesome!');
   $message->from('welcome@example.com', 'Website Name');
   $message->to($data['email']);
});
```

Comment: Does the domain show the green active tag in your mailgun account?

Comment: And what about your domain key? Have you added the `smtp._domainkey.mg` TXT record?

Comment: Ok I found the problem, but that's very strange to me.

Comment: The problem is in this line:  $message->from('welcome@example.com', 'Website Name');

Comment: the mailgun domain name is example.com and when I change it to something else it works, but if I leave the mailgun domain it goes to spam

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to create a separate sub-domain mg.example.com and add the mx, spf and dkim on there.

And update `.env` and `config/mail.php` with the new domain name.